# How to optimize jump like in Flappy Bird in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can write somehow this code for optimization?
If not use coroutines, when I click on space the next jump has more force and so on.
If use rb.MovePosition, the character will move as if 15 fps. I know, change Time in settings. But I want to know if exist another method...

```
private void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(Jump());
    }
}

private IEnumerator Jump() {
    if(rb.bodyType != RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic) {
        rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
    }

    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
    _pos = transform.position;

    for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime * 4f)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, _pos.y + .35f, transform.position.z), t);
        yield return null;
    }

    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigidbodies exist so you don't need to directly adjust an object's transform. Since you have a `Rigidbody2d` you can just set the velocity directly:

```
public float jumpSpeed = 5f; // Whatever feels right
private void FixedUpdate() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpSpeed;
    }
}
```

(Edited to use `velocity` instead of `AddForce`)

Comment: but this not work fine, if tapped lot time , player starts like to fly, if tappe one time and wait for ±.5s , second time will be jump just a little.

Comment: I understand you need to install on rigidbody.velocity = 0 before addforce

Comment: @NoName My bad; I miss understood how flappy bird works, you can just set the velocity directly.  I updated my answer